Supabase delete not working through javascript client api and postman
I'm trying to delete a row in a supabase table via the javascript client api (also tried postman later). Supabase is running on a remote server via docker. I'm working with Next.js, but all cache has been disabled for a time being for testing purposes, so the issue cannot lie there.
Curiously, adding and modifying rows works. Only delete fails.
  const { data, error } = await supabase.from("menus").delete().eq("id", "1");

  if (error) {
    console.error("Error deleting row:", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Row deleted:", data);
  }
  console.error(error);

According to the documentation, the above should work (the row with id=1 exists). Instead, it returns:

RLS is disabled. I tried using both the anon key and service_role key, with no success. Both roles have the superuser perms granted. Also given them perms to delete data.

I obviously checked the net and all the most common fixes, nothing worked.
EDIT
Table definition:


post the table definition and the policies - hard to say with just this

I added the Table Definition. When it comes to the policies, RLS is disabled for all tables.

I had same issue and turns out if you have RLS policy enabled, with delete policy, you also need to create policy on select. I guess the logic is that if one can't read data, they neither can delete it.
